# Calling class methods from inside class through locals()

Tags: python

I have a class with lots of methods whose names follow a pattern:

`convert_to_A(self)`, `convert_to_B(self)`, `convert_to_C(self)`, ...

The user is going to provide me a list of functions to call. Say something like -

```
user_options = ["A", "G", "K", ...]
```

and I just stumbled upon the awesome `globals()`, `locals()` functions which I think are going to solve my problem. So a method inside the function which calls them through `locals()` should work right? -

```
def call_user_options(self):
    for step in self.user_options:
        locals()["convert_to_" + step]()
```

But it didn't. Also tried calling `locals()["self.convert_to_" + step]()` but it was of no avail. Printing `locals()` and `globals()` gives this -

```
locals = {'self': <__main__.test instance at 0x105466200>}
globals = {'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__file__': 'globals_locals.py', '__package__': None, 'test': <class __main__.test at 0x105429ae0>, '__name__': '__main__', 'main': <function main at 0x10544bed8>, '__doc__': None}
```

So how do I exactly call those methods from a method inside the class when they're hidden behind `self` ?

Comment: Try: `getattr(self, "convert_to_" + step)()`.

Comment: This resolves it. Thanks!

Comment: I really don't recommend it, but you could also do something like: ``eval("convert_to_{}()".format(step))``. A major issue with this approach though is that you are executing whatever the user inputs without sanitizing it.